# Python Pandas: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Using Python Pandas and importing an Excel document, the following code is kicking back an error:

```
df['City'] = df['City'].astype(str)
df['Rent'] = np.where((df['City'].str.contains('ST PETERSBURG')) & (df['BedroomsTotal'] == 2),  df['Rent'], df['LivingArea'] * df['Multiplier'])
```

The mentioned error is:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

I added the top line to set the column to type string. They already should be strings since the column is a list of cities. Thoughts or suggestions on ways around this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: May you share your sample dataset ?

Comment: Yep. Please see screenshot

Comment: What are you expecting the `.str` to do?

Comment: Ultimately to solve the following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65313183/11144854

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Rent'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Rent if ('ST PETERSBURG' in x.City) & (x.BedroomsTotal==2) else x.LivingArea*x.Multiplier, axis=1)
```

Check for the conditions.